# What is the flow of control of recursive cte methods in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a query to solve [a question](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-people-report-to-the-given-manager/):

```
with recursive cte as(
    select employee_id from employees where manager_id = 1 and employee_id != 1
    union all
    select a.employee_id from employees a inner join cte b on b.employee_id=a.manager_id)

select employee_id from cte
```

I read the documentation and understood that the first line is the `anchor member`, the second line joins the result sets, third line is the subquery that references to the cte and hence, the recursion.

What I did not understand was the flow of control. For eg, a cte named `cte` is declared, we run a select query (the anchor), then we perform a union all with another result set that recursively calls this cte.

It is stated in the documentation that the recursion terminates once the result set is empty. I am not able to understand at what step of the flow will the recurion terminate.

Comment: Well, it ends, as stated in the documentation, when the "second" query returns an empty set. What in detail do you not understand about it?

Comment: How come would it return empty rows? It will always return all the rows, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is stated in the documentation that the recursion terminates once the result set is empty. I am not able to understand at what step of the flow will the recurion terminate.

Let's have a look at the recursive part of the CTE:

```
select a.employee_id 
from employees a 
inner join cte b on b.employee_id = a.manager_id
```

When does this return no rows? When there is no employee whose `manager_id` is equal to the `employee_id` of `cte`.

Basically, the query walks a hierarchical structure: at each step, it brings the *managees* of the current employee. When the current employee is not managing any employee, the recursive part comes back empty, and the recursion stops.